# Importing and committing multiple PIM contacts collectively

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can you import and commit multiple PIM contacts collectively?  Currently we are importing and committing each contact individually, which results in the user having to authorise each contact.

This is our code:

```
PIMItem[] pi = instance.fromSerialFormat(inputStream, "UTF8");
Contact contact = contactList.importContact((Contact) pi[0]);
contact.commit();
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to sign your application so the user gets the option to accept contact updates just once.